# complexity of the insertion sort using Doubly Linked List?

Tags: sorting, linked-list, complexity-theory, insertion-sort

> Insertion sort requires insertion of an element in sorted order by
>   shifting the elements of an already sorted list while implemented
>   through array. If instead of using arrays, we use doubly linked-list,
>   what would be the time complexity?

Time Complexity Comes out to be O(n^2)? Why? 
If we consider insertion for n elements then it will be 
log(1) + log(2) + log(3) + ..... + log(n) - n times for n elements
hence complexity should be O(nlogn)

Comment: What makes you think it's `log(1) + log(2) + ... + log(n)` and not `1 + 2 + ... + n` ? Please add more details in the questions, so you will get better more informative answers - which will be more likely to explain where your mistake is.

Comment: for insertion using insertion sort if we use doubly linked list then insertion of an element takes log(k) time where k is the number of already sorted elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insertion into a linked list takes time O(*n*), not O(lg *n*), because you have to navigate the link structure to find the insertion point.